# Why puppet module install --force does not install dependency & how to workaround?

Tags: module, vagrant, puppet

I'm working with vagrant & puppet to install my dev environment.

I use a shell provisioner to install the puppet's modules :

```
config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "puppet module install --force garethr-docker"
end
```

But when I launch `vagrant provision`, I see that puppet does not install the module dependencies (stdlib, apt & stahma-epel for this particular module).

On the other hand, if I remove `--force`, the dependencies are correctly installed, but `vagrant provision` will only work one time since puppet throw an error the second time ("module already installed").

**How can I overcome this ?**
**Thx.**

PS, my complete Vagrantfile :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "phusion/ubuntu-14.04-amd64"

  config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "puppet module install --force garethr-docker"
  end

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "dockervm.pp"
    puppet.options="--verbose --debug"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the module is installed before attempting to install it again. For instance:

```
{ puppet module list | grep garethr-docker > /dev/null; } || \
    puppet module install garethr-docker
```

Comment: Ah yes ! I didn't think to use a bit of bash scripting, i was looking for a more "cleaner" way with puppet directly.

Finally I use :

    if puppet module list | grep garethr-docker > /dev/null; then puppet module upgrade garethr-docker; else puppet module install garethr-docker; fi

Because I still want to update the module when i launch vagrant provision.